# Delete logs of containers docker for mac

Tags: docker

I'm trying to delete the logs of my containers. I'm using docker for mac.
For instance this command for the elasticsearch container

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' elasticsearch
```

will output

```
/var/lib/docker/containers/d4d426c49ee91447797e482b86b1eb5fd51f6a9257dd1f3a2391895abecf2b56/d4d426c49ee91447797e482b86b1eb5fd51f6a9257dd1f3a2391895abecf2b56-json.log
```

I know that this is not in my filesystem, but in the VM. When I used dinghy with VirtualBox I entered the machine with

```
docker-machine ssh :machine_name
```

With dinghy it was `dinghy`, in other cases it would be `default`.
And then I just deleted the log file.

I'm trying to get the active machine used in docker for mac with

```
docker-machine ls
```

but no machine is registered. I'm executing this

```
eval $(docker-machine env)
```

And the output is this

```
Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists.
```

I get the same output when I execute

```
docker-machine ip
```

Here a user says that with this setup we no longer have access to docker machine, which is fine, but is there a way to delete the logs?

https://forums.docker.com/t/how-to-find-docker-machine-ip-in-commandline-in-docker-beta-os-x/9844/5

Comment: Hi @MartinAhrer I found out later on, but I forgot to update this. Please post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this question is quite old and may have been answered somewhere else: The reason why this doesn't work is that Docker For Mac does not use a docker-machine managed virtual machine. See docs.docker.com/machine/get-started/#prerequisite-informatio‌​n. It is using a Hyperkit lightweight engine.